Including a man page when installing project with cargo
I'm creating a CLI tool in Rust. I have written a man page for it (i.e., a file for use with Linux's man command). I want to include it with my project, such that people can cargo install my-project then use man my-project to see its man page.
I've tried running man on commands I've installed using cargo in the hopes that I could reference their repositories, but I've had no luck.
Failing all else, my solution would be to download the page from the cloud to /usr/share/man on the first run / check if the page is present and download it otherwise. My issues with this solution include that it requires access to the internet (whereas other functionality in the tool does not), and downloading the file could take some time on slow connections.
Is there a better (or even suggested/accepted) way to install a man page along with a rust project using cargo install?

There is the "man" crate which lets you create a man page in code. Could this be an option?

Or look at other installable projects that feature a man page, like eza

cargo install installs binaries and nothing else. There's some hacks around that, but none work properly e.g. on cargo uninstall. If you're happy with managing the man page from your own binary, but don't want to require a network connection, include!ing it in the binary might work. For my own CLI projects, I find that the --help flag generated e.g. by clap is good enough and I don't need a man page.
